# How to create a vertical button in vuetify

Tags: vuejs2, vuetify.js

How do I rotate a button in vuetify and move it to the right edge as shown in below picture.
1. Button's height should be as same as of the page.
2. Button's label should be on top and vertical as shown below.

[image: Desired page]

Answer (score 0):

Click

```css
#button1 {
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(-90deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(-90deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(-90deg);
  transform-origin: bottom right;
  margin-left: 280px;
  margin-top:-63px;
}
p{
   align-items: flex-top;
  transform: rotate(180deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(180deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(180deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(180deg);
  transform-origin: bottom;
}
```